# BeautifulSoup copy table header to footer

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML table that only has a `<thead>` but has no `<tfoot>`.
Needing to use BeautifulSoup to copy the header to the footer.

The table looks like this:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, I need it to look like this:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>          
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I'm thinking I need to use insert_after, but I am struggling to see how I copy the content of the thead, create the new tfoot, and insert the `<tr>` and `<th>` values.
I tried at first to loop through the object and create tags and the `insert_after`:

```
table_headers = soup.find_all('th')
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?  I was surprised that inserting the `soup.thead.tr` object removed it from the  element.  Note the `copy()`

```
    from copy import copy

    orig = """<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    """

    soup = BeautifulSoup(orig)
    tfoot = soup.new_tag('tfoot')
    # XXX: if you don't copy() the object the <tr> element is removed from <thead>
    tfoot.append(copy(soup.thead.tr))
    soup.tbody.insert_after(tfoot)
```